# C++ Card related program will not compile. (Run-time error)

Tags: c++

Does anyone know why my program is getting a run time error and crashing? I can't seem to figure it out. There seems to be no debugging options. It just simply crashes upon launch. Please help me answer my question fully and be kind about it. I hope you all can help me.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Card {
    private:
        string suit;
        string face;
        int number;

    public:
        Card (string cardsuit , int cardnumber){
            suit = cardsuit;
            number = cardnumber;
        }

        Card () {
            suit = "";
            number = 0;
        }

        void setcard (string cardsuit){
            suit = cardsuit;
        }

        void setnumber( int cardnumber){
            number = cardnumber;
        }

        void display() {
            if(number == 0) {
                cout << "" ;
            }
            else
                (cout << number << " of " << suit << endl)  ;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Card acard[52];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++){
        acard[i] = Card("Hearts " , i+1);
    }  

    for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++) {
        acard[i+13] = Card("Diamonds " , i+1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++) {
        acard[i+26] = Card("Clubs " , i+1);
    }

   for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++) {
        acard[i+39] = Card("Spades " , i+1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        acard[i].display();
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### A logic error...

You functionally overwrite the "14 of Hearts" with the "1 of Diamonds". You also do this on the rest of the suits as well.

```
acard[i] = Card("Hearts " , i+1);      // i is 13
acard[i+13] = Card("Diamonds " , i+1); // i is 0
```

#### Writing beyond the end of an array...

During the last for loop, the last iteration writes beyond the end of the array with:

```
acard[i+39] = Card("Spades " , i+1);   // i is 13
```

#### Also...

Having the `cout` expression within `Card::display()` in parentheses is just odd.

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are actually writing 14 cards each:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++){
    // ...
```

Running from 0 to 13 inclusive, when they should run from 0 to 12 (or from 1 to 13, there's no need to start at 0 each time either).

The fourteenth card for Hearts, Diamonds and Clubs is overwritten in the loop for the next suit, with no other ill effects, but the `for` loop for Spades is actually writing the fourteenth card out of the array's bounds, hence the crash.